# How to make sso secure without consuming so many resources.?

Tags: php, single-sign-on

Lets say i have 2 different applications i.e X and Y. Both of which are properly configured with third party identity provider (SSO service provider).

Now  a new client comes to my X application. He loves what i have to offer and he thought why not register into it.

So he registered to my application X and as i am using an SSO system all my users information is gonna go to the identity provider.

Our new user is successfully logged in now.

My  real question comes here. Here i go.

Everytime user perform some action on the protected end points on my website. Do i always have to verify his identity.? Do i always have to find out  if the user have a valid acces_token or not by sending a request to my identity provider from my back channel.

That means every time user will send a request to my server I'll verify it from my identity provider.

Which means for each request there are actuall 2 requests.  My server have to wait before it can do something until the identity provider tells this is a verified user.

It feels like a lot of cost to performance.

Is there another way.? I'll really appreciate that if you can tell me?

Comment: Please improve your question title to better represent your isolated issue so that your question is more "searchable".

Comment: Its a long question what should i say in title

Comment: Why should SSO check if the user has access or not, won't it be server's policy that allows/denies whether or not user can access?

Comment: @SaileshD i think you haven't read the question. Carefully

Comment: You can use sessions to hold the current user information over the span of multiple requests. This way you only need to check with the IP once to see if the access_token is valid and for how long it is valid. After that you don't need to ask the IP again.

Comment: @Progman What If My Application Is pure javascript app? We cant use sessions there.

Comment: @QaMarALi When it is fully javascript, you can save the access_token and the lifetime in the javascript app directly like in cookies or local storage. Then it's the same that you don't need to check the IP for each request.